# Portable native client Permission denied when resolving host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I am writing a small application to test and understand PNaCl.

The aim of the application is to resolve an host name a the ip of an host using [HostResolver](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_host_resolver) class from PNaCl framework. The code seems to work properly but I am getting an access denied error (return value -7) because I haven't asked the permission to access the socket layer (I guess) to the user. The problem is that I have no idea how to do so. I trie to write a manifest file, but nothing happened.

Note : this application must run on the open Web and it must not require any installation process.
I don't want to write a Chrome app.

I haven't found any clue online so I would appreciate your help.

**hello_tuttorial.cc:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>


#include "ppapi/cpp/instance.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/module.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/var.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/tcp_socket.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/host_resolver.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/module.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/tcp_socket.h"
#include "ppapi/c/pp_errors.h"
#include "ppapi/utility/completion_callback_factory.h"


namespace {
  // exptected string from the browser 
  const char * const kHelloString = "hello"; 
  // the sting sent from the nacl module to the browser
  const char * const kReplyString ="hello from the PNaCl"; 
} 


class HelloTutorialInstance : public pp::Instance {

  pp::CompletionCallbackFactory<HelloTutorialInstance> callback_factory_;
  pp::TCPSocket tcp_socket_;
  pp::HostResolver resolver_;

 public:
  explicit HelloTutorialInstance(PP_Instance instance) : pp::Instance(instance),
      callback_factory_(this)
      {}

  virtual ~HelloTutorialInstance() {}

  virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) { 
    if (!var_message.is_string())
      return; 

    std::string message = var_message.AsString(); 
    pp::Var var_reply; 

    test_socket_support(); 

     if( message == kHelloString){
      var_reply = pp::Var("So far so good"); 
      PostMessage(var_reply); 
    }

  }

 private:

 void test_socket_support(){

  if (!pp::TCPSocket::IsAvailable()) {
      PostMessage("TCPSocket not available");
      return;
    }

  tcp_socket_ = pp::TCPSocket(this);

  if (tcp_socket_.is_null()) {
      PostMessage("Error creating TCPSocket.");
      return;
   }

  if (!pp::HostResolver::IsAvailable()) {
    PostMessage("HostResolver not available");
    return;
  }

  resolver_ = pp::HostResolver(this);
  if (resolver_.is_null()) {
    PostMessage("Error creating HostResolver.");
    return;
  }


  int port = 80;
  pp::CompletionCallback callback = \
      callback_factory_.NewCallback(&HelloTutorialInstance::OnResolveCompletion);
  PP_HostResolver_Hint hint = { PP_NETADDRESS_FAMILY_UNSPECIFIED, 0 };
  resolver_.Resolve("http://www.google.com", port, hint, callback);
  PostMessage("Resolving ...");

  }

 void OnResolveCompletion(int32_t result) {
  if (result != PP_OK) {
    char str[100] = {0}; 
    sprintf(str, "Resolved failed %d", result);
    PostMessage(str);

    if( result == PP_ERROR_NOACCESS )
        PostMessage("Access denied");
    return;
  }

  pp::NetAddress addr = resolver_.GetNetAddress(0);
  PostMessage(std::string("Resolved: ") +
              addr.DescribeAsString(true).AsString());

  }
}; 

class HelloTutorialModule : public pp::Module {
 public:
  HelloTutorialModule() : pp::Module() {}
  virtual ~HelloTutorialModule() {}

  virtual pp::Instance* CreateInstance(PP_Instance instance) {
    return new HelloTutorialInstance(instance);
  }
};

namespace pp {
  Module* CreateModule() {
  return new HelloTutorialModule();
  }
}  // namespace pp
```

**Manifest.json :**

```
{
  "name": "hello_tutorial",
  "version": "31.0.1650.57",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "socket Example",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": [
    {
        "socket": [
            "tcp-listen:*:*", 
            "tcp-connect", 
            "resolve-host", 
            "udp-bind:*:*", 
            "udp-send-to:*:*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<div id="listener">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var listener = document.getElementById('listener');
    listener.addEventListener('load', moduleDidLoad, true);
    listener.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, true);
  </script>

  <embed id="hello_tutorial"
         width=0 height=0
         src="hello_tutorial.nmf"
         type="application/x-pnacl" />
</div>
```

**OutPut:**

```
Resolving ... 
So far so good
Resolved failed -7 
Access denied
```

Answer (score 7):

Only packaged apps from the chrome store can use the sockets API.

You can access sockets for development by setting the '[--allow-nacl-socket-api=foo](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)' flag when you start Chrome. Replace 'foo' with the host name that you're loading your app from. 'localhost' if you're loading from your local machine. Note that you should **not** enable the 'allow-nacl-socket-api' option on 'about:flags'. This overrides the command line option but does not include a list of authorized hosts, so the result is that no host has permission to use the sockets API.

Answer (score 0):

pp::HostResolver and other raw socket interfaces can only be used by Chrome Apps, not on the open web. See [here](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_host_resolver#details).

Also, if you do decide to make a Chrome App, see the documentation [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html). You can't just add a `manifest.json` file, you also have to specify a background script that will launch your App.